# Spring MVC response type inheritance: Missing sub class fields

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a controller method:

**CarController**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/cars")
public class CarController {
    @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public CarsResponse getAll() {
        Car car = new ManualCar("make", 5);
        List<? extends Car> cars = Lists.newArrayList(car);
        return new CarsResponse(cars);
    }
}
```

**Response Class**

```
public class CarsResponse {
    private final List<? extends Car> cars;
    //... Constructor ...
    public List<? extends Car> getCars() {
        return this.cars;
    }
}
```

**Models**

```
public abstract class Car {
    private final String make;
    //... Constructor ...
    public String getMake() {
        return this.make;
    }
}

public class ManualCar extends Car {
    private final int gearCount;
    //... Constructor ...
    public int getGearCount() {
        return this.gearCount;
    }
}
```

Now when I call my `/cars` endpoint I only get the fields from the `Car` class in my JSON, not the extra fields from `ManualCar`.

Is there some annotations missing? How do I get it so my sub class fields appear as in the response as well as the base class fields?

I would expect the response to look like:

```
{
    "cars": [{
        "make": "make",
        "gearCount": 5
     }]
 }
```

But it instead looks like:

```
{
    "cars": [{
        "make": "make"
     }]
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I literally copied your code to an empty project I had, added the missing constructors (did you plan to save 2 lines of output by omitting them in OP?), and replaced `Lists.newArrayList` (where's that one from, Guava?) with a standard Java variant `Collections.singletonList`, and got the output `{"cars":[{"make":"make","gearCount":5}]}`. So maybe your issue is with how the Guava creates the lists? The rest of the code seems fine, and works fine, too.

Comment: It turned out the constructor code I had omitted was doing some mapping which was dropping the extra fields. It wasnt anything Guava related though.